# NoReverseMatch exception - redirect with keyword arguments

Tags: django

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error when trying to use Django's redirect, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

In views:

```
def addConjugatedForm(request):
    #update database
    return redirect('findConjugatedForms', chapter=ch.chapter, verse=verse.verse, book=b.name)

def findConjugatedForms(request, book, chapter, verse):
    #return a view
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^findConjugatedForms/(?P<book>\w+)/(?P<chapter>\d+)/(?P<verse>\d+)/', 'findConjugatedForms'),
```

The url works as a url, i.e. "...findConjugatedForms/Romans/3/24" returns a page. But when a form on that page is submitted, it won't redirect back.

I have named arguments in my url (which seems to be the common problem in other questions on Stack Overflow) and the values of the kwargs seem to be correct.

```
Reverse for 'findConjugatedForms' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'chapter': 3, 'verse': 24, 'book': u'Romans'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` uses [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)  internally. You need to define a viewname for the url, or use a Python path or pass a callable object:

```
url(r'^findConjugatedForms/(?P<book>\w+)/(?P<chapter>\d+)/(?P<verse>\d+)/',
    'findConjugatedForms',
    name='findConjugatedForms')  # Define a name
```

Besides, add a suffix `'$'` into the pattern to prevent the url from matching other urls that starts with `findConjugatedForms/book/chapter/verse/`